# How do I make my bomb destroy all enemies in a certain radius?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a game where you evade enemies and trigger certain powerups that has various effects on the enemies. One of them is a bomb that explodes 4 seconds after the player collides with it, destroying all enemies within its radius as it explodes.

I think I've got everything figured out except the actual destroying of the enemy. I feel like the solution is so obvious but I just never learned the method. At this point the bomb object is destroyed upon explosion instead of the enemies, which I expected to happen, because Destroy(other.gameObject) just doesn't work in this context! What do I do??

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("player");
            StartCoroutine(BombCountdownRoutine());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator BombCountdownRoutine()
    {
        bombAudio.PlayOneShot(bombSound, 0.8f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < hitColliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (hitColliders[i].gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your case, the enemy is each hitCollider in the hitColliders array. You already get the gameobject's tag inside your if statement, so just do `Destroy(hitColliders[i].gameObject);` and you should be fine.

Comment: To add to what D.Christodoulou said, your current code reads like this: "Let me find all the things nearby that might be enemies. Let me look at each one. Hey I found an enemy! <destroy self>"

Comment: Hahaha yes it worked perfectly! I still am very new at all of this but as soon as I asked the question it came to me. At the end of the day its jut about understanding how the software thinks and then being able to speak it's language. But thank you!